# Remote debugging a process that crashes on launch using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, remote-debugging

I recently converted a mingw/cygwin build to a Visual C++ cl.exe build and upon initial testing found it crashes at launch. I then installed it in my developer environment to debug it, under which it runs just fine. My initial suspicion was that I was linking to a different DLL in that context, but examining both processes in both contexts with Process Explorer showed that they were using the same versions of the same DLLs.

Since I can't reproduce the issue with Visual C++ installed I installed the remote debugger on the client machine, but I can't manage to attach to the process quickly enough before it crashes. Is there a good way to go about doing this? This would be easy if I could launch the process under the debugger locally, but that doesn't look like a viable option here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be letting the remote debugger start the debugee process on the remote machine.

Comment: Yes, don't do a Debug | Process Attach, just do a F5 Debug, but with the remote debugger set in the Debug Settings, then it will catch startup crashes.

Comment: "just do a F5 Debug, but with the remote debugger set in the Debug Settings"  What does this mean??

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but I was looking for how to do this in VS 2022 today.

1. Right click on the project that you want to debug and go to Properties
2. Under "Debug/General", click on "Open debug launch profiles UI"
3. Tick "Use remote machine".
4. Fill in the remote machine name and port, set authentication mode.
5. Build your project
6. Create an identical folder structure on the remote machine as on your developer machine, e.g. {Project Path}/bin/... and copy the output from your build.
7. Launch the debugger with F5